# C++ Dumping stack trace to *.exe.stackdump

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, stack-trace

Was writing some code for an assignment to take integers as input and place them in an array to be printed.

I'm cleaning up all of my pointers as far as I can tell but I keep getting the runtime error:

`1 [main] new 3444 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to new.exe.stackdump`

body of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int array[10];
int * p = array;

int *readNumbers()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        string number;
        int numb;
        cout << "enter digit " << i << " of 10" << endl;
        getline(cin, number);
        istringstream (number) >> numb;
        array[i]=numb;
    }
    return p;
    delete p;
}

void printNumbers(int *numbers,int length) 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        cout << i << " " << *(numbers+i) << endl;
    }
}
```

and the main calling code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern int *readNumbers();
extern void printNumbers(int *,int);


int main()
{
    int * q = readNumbers();
    printNumbers(q,10);
    delete q;
    return 0;
}
```

So just looking for a solution to the stack dump...
Also I'm sure the method I used to apply the `string number` returned by `cin` to the values contained in `array[10]` is not what the question was looking for so any notes on that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: The best solution depend on your dev environment, so you need to explain more about your OS, compiler, IDE, etc.

Comment: Side-note: `delete p;` after `return p;` is never executed. Why would you delete something that wasn't allocated with new anyway? That actually applies to `delete q;` in your main function, which I believe is the root-cause of your crash

Comment: You should not delete q in your main calling code since q is pointed to array

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to return a pointer to a memory allocated inside a function, in this case, you are not even allocating it inside a function, you have done it in a global space.
It is a good practice to activate all your warnings during the compile, even treat them as error when you are doing an assignment.
As a tip, you can allocate the memory in your main function and then pass the pointer to the readNumbers function.T This way it remains inside the same scope and it is easier to manage.
also, the same way you pass the lenght of the array to the printnumbers function you should pass it to the readnumbers one instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete` are invalid, you can only delete something you've allocated with `new`.

The first one is harmless because it's after a return, so never executed (BTW you should look at compiler warnings).

The second one might produce your crash.

```
Also I'm sure the method I used to apply the string number returned by cin to the values contained in array[10] is not what the question was looking for so any notes on that would be great.
```

That's OK. What's dubious is spreading the size of the array everywhere, what happens if you want to change it ?